# Process in CActiveDataProvider or CGridView

Tags: yii, cgridview, cactivedataprovider

I have a table called City, table contain field IsMetro it is bit(1), so it can store 1 or 0, i have generated model for this table and generated CRUD operation forms.

Now i want True instead of 1 and False instead of 0.

Where should i perform this operation in CActiveDataProvider or CGridView and how to do this

i am getting this output

```
CityId - City Name - IsMetro-(bit(1))
1        A           1
```

i want this output

```
CityId - City Name - IsMetro-(bit(1))
1        A           True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

In views admin.php

```
array(
    'name'=>'IsMetro',
    'value'=>'$data->IsMetro=="1"?"TRUE":"FALSE"',
      ),
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in CGridView  column by using the property `value`. In you column you can write like this

```
 array(

            'header' => 'IsMetro',
            'htmlOptions' => array('style' => 'text-align:center;'),
            'value'=>'($data->IsMetro==1)?"True":"False"',
        ),
```